# Uploading files with PhoneGap + iPhone

Tags: iphone, file-upload, cordova

I understand that PhoneGap applications are largely (if not entirely) HTML5 + CSS + JavaScript. Natively, the iPhone doesn't provide controls to upload files.

Does PhoneGap provide any mechanisms that allow users to upload files? (images / video, in the case of the iPhone)

I know Titanium allows users to do this, but it's a different animal with its compiled Javascript and proprietary APIs. Thanks for your advice/input.

Comment: Check this post out (linking has changed since this was orignally posted): http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap

Comment: The iPhone now does provides a native control to upload images.

Comment: Seriously? `<input type="file" />` will work now as of iOS 7?

Comment: Yeah. Even in iOS 6. It'll ask the user to either choose a picture from the Camera Roll or to take a new picture.

Comment: This is news to me (I never upgraded past iOS 5). Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you might be able to read the files using the [PhoneGap API](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File) and the upload them using and AJAX post if  the server application supported it.

The other option is to write a custom module/Plugin in PhoneGap that could specific to your needs.

Here are some [Example Plugins](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins)

Comment: Looks like that is about as close as it gets. Any idea if reading / POSTing files in this manner will overload the memory? Not sure if it tries to buffer the whole thing before it goes for it.

Comment: i have no idea, haven't really tried before, but you could always writ a plugin, they are not that hard. I have written one to download code. All the source is posted here http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/2056122828/phonegap-plugin-for-downloading-url-all-the-code

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't seen a plugin in action yet. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score -1):

You can do an xmlhttprequest to the file on a local drive.
I'm not 100% sure if it will work on the iPhone, but webkit should support it.

```
function getImageBinaries(url) { //synchronous binary downloader for firefox2

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", url, false);

req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');

req.send("");
if (req.status != 200) {
    return "";
}
var t = req.responseText || "" ;
var ff = [];
var mx = t.length;
var scc= String.fromCharCode;
for (var z = 0; z < mx; z++) {
    ff[z] = scc(t.charCodeAt(z) & 255);
}
var b = ff.join("");
return b;
}
```

Succes,
Erik

Comment: Yes, but then you have the binaries.
you can then encode them into a base64 string and use that to upload the file. You can put the base64 into a field if you want to post it. Just don't forget to make a little change in your server side to decode it. It's better then making a <input type='file'/> as that isn't supported on all devices (including the iPhone).
you can either post this data, or do a httprequest with it.