# Posting image to FaceBook wall from iPhone camera roll with PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, image, facebook, cordova, publish

I am using **PhoneGap** to publish an **image** to a **FaceBook wall** from an **iPhone**.

I am able to log in a FaceBook account and publish a HOSTED image (`http://www.mysite.com/my_image.jpg`) but not an image from the iPhone.

Here is the script to post to FB:

```
function fbPost() {
    $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed",
           data: {
                message: "<FACEBOOK MESSAGE>",
                PICTURE: "<IMAGE URL>",
                name: "<TITLE OF POST>",
                link: "<LINK TO APP>",
                caption: "<SHOWN BELOW TITLE>",
                description: "<SHOWN BELOW CAPTION>",
                access_token: access_token,
                format: "json"
           },
           success: function (data) {
               navigator.notification.alert("success!", null, "Thanks!")
           },
                   },
           dataType: "json",
           timeout: 10000
           })
}
```

Here is the code to get an image from the iPhone (camera roll or album):

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI }); 

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = imageURI;
}
```

(http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html).

When I use an image from the iPhone, the URI of the image is something like: 
`file:///var/mobile/Applications/..../Documents/tmp/photo_001.jpg`

Again, I am able to publish an image when I specify a hosted (`http://...`) image, but not when it's an image from the iPhone.

I would greatly apreciate any help.

Thank you.

Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook can not access a local file on your telephone. I dont know about the ways you can upload a photo to facebook, but as you said before it works if you use a public hosted file.

So I think you got two choices here:
Upload the foto to a server an then post the url of the file to facebook. (you can use the file api of phonegap to do that, theres event an upload plugin), but i think this is not really a good solution.

I would suggest to find if you can post the image data to facebook (maybe base64 encoded) and use the phonegap api to get the base64 encoded content of the foto and post this directly to facebook

Comment: Thank you Daniel. The PhoneGap API has the option of getting the captured image as a base64-encoded string: `document.getElementById('image').src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;` but it does not work either. At least not when I then put `picture:"document.getElementById('image').src"`

Comment: i took a quick look at the facebook api and they only accept a url. so you need to upload the image. a good way to do this can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307877/uploading-files-with-phonegap-iphone

Answer (score 2):

I write a PhoneGap plug-in use [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to post photos from iPhone/iPad to Facebook. This plug-in can also post photo with Facebook place id (means it can **Checkin Facebook with photo**) and works fine on iOS 6.0.

It's based on PhoneGap 2.1 and [phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect), and **not need** any middle host, maybe it can solve your problem ;)

First, the **PhotoCheckin.h** is...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Facebook.h"
#import "FBConnect.h"

#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface PhotoCheckin : CDVPlugin
<FBDialogDelegate>

- (void) sendPost:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end
```

Second, **PhotoCheckin.m** as follow.

```
#import "PhotoCheckin.h"
#import "FBSBJSON.h"

@implementation PhotoCheckin

- (void) sendPost:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0]]]];
    NSString* message = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString* place_id = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:2];
    NSLog(@"%@",message);

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:image, @"source",message,@"message",place_id, @"place", nil];

    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                     parameters:params
                                     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                  NSString *resultStr = nil;
                                  if (error) {
                                      //resultStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"error: domain = %@, code = %d",error.domain, error.code];
                                      resultStr = [[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_JSON_EXCEPTION messageAsString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"error: domain = %@, code = %d",error.domain, error.code]] toErrorCallbackString:command.callbackId];
                                  }else{
                                      //resultStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Posted action, id: %@",[result objectForKey:@"id"]];
                                      resultStr = [[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Posted action, id: %@",[result objectForKey:@"id"]]] toSuccessCallbackString:command.callbackId];
                                  }
                                  //[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Check-in Result" message:resultStr delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
                                  [self writeJavascript:resultStr];
                              }];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"no active session");

        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"publish_stream",nil];
        // more "permissions strings" at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

        // OPEN Session
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                      FBSessionState status,
                                                      NSError *error) {
                                      if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status)) {
                                          [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Got FB session!" message:@"please check-in again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
                                      }else{
                                          [self writeJavascript:[[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_JSON_EXCEPTION messageAsString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"error: domain = %@, code = %d",error.domain, error.code]] toErrorCallbackString:command.callbackId]];
                                          /*[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Fail"
                                                                      message:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                                               @"error: domain = %@, code = %d",
                                                                               error.domain, error.code]
                                                                     delegate:self
                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                            otherButtonTitles:nil]
                                           show];*/
                                      }
                                  }];
    }
}


@end
```

Notes: this method will callback when posted, some code lines were commented out, which can make alert to users.

Third, the **PhotoCheckin.js** as follow.

```
var PhotoCheckin = {
    sendPost: function(photo_uri, message, place_id, success, fail) {
        return Cordova.exec(success, fail, "PhotoCheckin", "sendPost", [photo_uri, message, place_id]);
    }
}
```

Finally, when we went to use the plug-in, we write js as follow. (in .html/.js)

```
PhotoCheckin.sendPost(photo_uri, message, place_id,
    function(result){
        navigator.notification.confirm(
            'message: '+result,
            null,
            'Photo Posted',
            'OK'
        );
    },
    function(error){
        navigator.notification.confirm(
            'message: '+error,
            null,
            'Photo Fail',
            'OK'
        );
    }
);
```

Notes: **photo_uri** is the photo's uri (e.g. file:///...), **message** is user's comment and **place_id** is the place id in Facebook (e.g. 106522332718569).

And like other plug-ins, we must to edit *Resources/Cordova.plist*, add **photoCheckin** as key and **PhotoCheckin** as value in plugins. And put **PhotoCheckin.h**&**PhotoCheckin.m** to folder named *Plugins*, include **PhotoCheckin.js** file in your js code.

have fun! from 台灣 :)

Comment: So what is it that enables post images on the phone (and not only hosted ones)? It would be good if your answer would explain that.

Comment: Like other native objective-C iOS apps can post local photo to FB by Graph API ([Code Example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11974972/1776862)), I use native code to handle photo upload :)